# Need Help Reading JSON objects

Tags: python, json

```
import urllib
import json
url = "http://iaspub.epa.gov/enviro/efservice/getEnvirofactsUVDAILY/ZIP/{ZIP Code}/JSON"
url = url.replace("{ZIP Code}", "92507")
print url
jsonurl = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = (jsonurl.read())
text = json.dumps(data)
print text
```

The print returns this:
`"[{\"ZIP_CODE\":92507,\"UV_INDEX\":8,\"UV`_ALERT\":0}]"
This is not a JSON object as well as this is not what I see in the url.

The url returns `[{"ZIP_CODE":92507,"UV_INDEX":8,"UV_ALERT":0}]`

I don't understand where the extra slashes are coming from.

Also, how would I just print for example the zip code by itself instead of printing out the entire text?

Answer (score 0):

The extra slashes are " escaped.

For example, you declare a string:

`"le_string" -> le_string`

But if you want to represent a " inside that string:

`"le_\"string\"" -> le_"string"`

When you are representing JSON objects you must declare the keys with "", so

`"{\"key\": \"value\" }" -> { "key": "value" }`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Lets say that instead of printing out the entire text, I just want a portion of it like the zip code. Would I have to include the the escape key when I try to print it out?

Comment: @Ria No, if you parse that string into an JSON object, you don't need to care about escaping charaters when accessing the object values

Answer (score 0):

As Strings in java are written inside double quotes, we use escape sequence \ to tell the String to ignore double quotes inside it whenever there is an escape sequence preceding the double quote.

For example, you have a regular String without any quotation marks, in Java you initialize it like this

```
String s = "I spend most of my time in Stackoverflow";
```

If there is a String with double quotation marks then you have to use escape sequence \

```
String t = "\"I spend most of my time in Stackoverflow\" said the developer";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib
import json
url = "http://iaspub.epa.gov/enviro/efservice/getEnvirofactsUVDAILY/ZIP/{ZIP Code}/JSON"
url = url.replace("{ZIP Code}", "92507")
print url
jsonurl = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = (jsonurl.read())
## Below to show data without escape characters
print data

## To print `ZIP_CODE` from the json
print [e['ZIP_CODE'] for e in json.loads(data)]
```

I don't think you need any of these json.loads() / json.dumps() properties. Basically these property are similar to encode / stringify respectively.

json.loads() encoding basic python object

json.dumps() JSON object decoding

Don't miss to test the code in [runnable](http://goo.gl/kSaf90)

Comment: Using loads, it replaces the slashes with a u                                                            `[{u'UV_INDEX': 8, u'UV_ALERT': 0, u'ZIP_CODE': 92507}]`

Comment: @Ria I think you can just print data. you don't need any of these json.dumps / json.loads. Updating my answer as per this.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies here:

```
text = json.dumps(data)
```

You're telling the JSON library to encode `data` as JSON. Since data is already a JSON string this will cause the JSON library to escape all quotation marks in the string. You've now got a string containing a JSON string of JSON - this is not what you want =)

You want to do:

```
array = json.loads(data)
```

That will give you a list of dictionaries that corresponds to the JSON array of JSON objects that you got in response from the HTTP call.

To access and print the zip code you do:

```
# Get the first dictionary/JSON object
object = array[0]
# Get the ZIP_CODE property from the dictionary/JSON object
zip_code = object["ZIP_CODE"] 
print(zip_code)
```

> 92507